# How to interact with unfocused window?

Tags: autoit

I am looking for a way to interact with dynamic windows while out of focus. I believe `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` are what I am looking for but I don't understand the parameters. I do not want to use `ControlSend` or `ControlClick` as the window to control will change constantly.

Specifically, I want to "set" a window to be the handle and while the mouse is hovering over that window all clicks are intercepted and sent to the window at the current mouse location and all keystrokes are sent as well. Think of the Windows 10 feature "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them".

```
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <WinAPISysWin.au3>

HotKeySet("`","focus")
HotKeySet("{F1}","msg")
Global $focus, $hwnd, $hwnd2

While 1
   Switch GUIGetMsg()
      Case -3
         Exit
   EndSwitch
   Sleep(100)
   check()
WEnd

Func focus() ;Sets the window to be interacted with
   $pos = _WinAPI_GetMousePos()
   $hwnd2 = _WinAPI_WindowFromPoint($pos)
   While _WinAPI_GetParent($hwnd2) <> 0
      $hwnd2 = _WinAPI_GetParent($hwnd2)
   WEnd
   $focus = _WinAPI_GetClassName($hwnd2)
EndFunc

Func msg() ;Checks that a window is set
   MsgBox(0, "", "Window set is: " & $focus)
EndFunc

Func check() ;Gets title and class of handle
   $pos = _WinAPI_GetMousePos()
   $hwnd = _WinAPI_WindowFromPoint($pos)
   While _WinAPI_GetParent($hwnd) <> 0
      $hwnd = _WinAPI_GetParent($hwnd)
   WEnd
   $title = WinGetTitle($hwnd)
   $class = _WinAPI_GetClassName($hwnd)
   If $class = $focus Then ;Checks on if current mouse position is over controlled window
   ;Routes all hotkeys minus tilde to controlled window
      For $i = 32 To 38
         HotKeySet(Chr($i), "Hotkeyfunc")
      Next
      For $i = 40 To 95
         HotKeySet(Chr($i), "Hotkeyfunc")
      Next
      For $i = 97 To 126
         HotKeySet(Chr($i), "Hotkeyfunc")
      Next
   Else
   ;Unroutes all hotkeys minus tilde to controlled window
      For $i = 32 To 38
         HotKeySet(Chr($i))
      Next
      For $i = 40 To 95
         HotKeySet(Chr($i))
      Next
      For $i = 97 To 126
         HotKeySet(Chr($i))
      Next
   EndIf
EndFunc

Func Hotkeyfunc() ;Sends keys to controlled window
   ControlSend($hwnd, "", "Edit1", @HotKeyPressed)
EndFunc
```

The above code sends all keystrokes to a Notepad document while hovering over, however I cannot simulate keystrokes. I would appreciate some help removing `ControlSend` and utilizing Post/Send. Also, Notepad will not always be the desired window, sometimes Chrome, sometimes email, etc.

Comment: instead of setting/unsetting all of those hotkeys, i would instead look up how to do mouse and keyboard hooks with autoit.

Comment: I have tried searching for hooks as well and again it is just so over my head. I am sure my example is not at all the right way to do what I want but I wanted to showcase that I have been trying and it's what I can come up with in my rookie knowledge. Could you whip up or provide me with a very basic example of hooking an application and what it does/how to utilize it?

Comment: [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/95106-remap-keys-using-keyboard-hook/) is a basic example. While this script is running, every time a key is pressed, the _KeyProc() function will run. In that example, the function will do something specific when the "a" key is pressed, but you can have it do anything, like just ControlSend($hwnd, "", "Edit1", $vkCode) will maybe work? Please be careful with keyboard hooks as it can basically disable your entire keyboard if used incorrectly...

Comment: Super hard for me to understand but I can start to digest it once I know what the "a" key function is doing? It is replacing the letter "a" with NumPad 0 (hex 0x60) Although I show 0x41 is right parenthesis and 0x60 is less than? these parameters ($wParam, $lParam) DLL calls and so on are foreign to me.

Comment: The "0x" before a number indicates that is it hexadecimal. Hexadecimal 41 is equal to decimal 65 which is the [virtual key code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) (and also the [ASCII code](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html)) for "A".

Comment: How can I obtain the Hex for @HotKeyPressed? Simply Hex(@HotKeyPressed) returns 000000